# Uncorrected DRAM ECC error

Tags: central-processing-unit, memory, bios, ecc

I am using SuperMicro server, AMI BIOS, Kingston ECC 8g registered RAM and Intel X5690.

After booted up, BMC responding:

```
Un-Correctable DRAM ECC Error Detected at CPU01/Channel01/DIMM0A
Press F1 to resume

--- ipmitools ----
   2 | 06/24/2011 | 17:55:33 | Memory | Uncorrectable ECC | Asserted
   5 | 06/28/2011 | 11:23:16 | Memory | Uncorrectable ECC | Asserted
------------
```

This happens only only 2 times but this is never shown after rebooted for 20 times.

- is the error self corrected?
- is ram or slot error?

Please advise.

Answer (score 5):

You can try reseating and/or rearranging the RAM, then test throughly. If it passes then it can be chalked up to seating alignment, but if it still comes up as a detected issue, then you need to seriously consider its replacement. If the same slot comes back up with a different module in its place, then you may want to take a closer look at the slot/motherboard itself.

A lot of RAM manufacturers offer good warranty periods, quite a few with life-time terms, so its worth looking into that as well.